# Pyspark runs on only two nodes in bash mode

Tags: python-2.7, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a YARN cluster with 7 nodes. My goal is to run a simple PySpark program of the form

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

def func(s):
        return processed_s

sc = SparkContext("yarn-client", "App-name")
arr= [Dataset]
par= sc.parallelize(arr)
out= par.map(func)
stuff=out.collect()
print stuff
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I try to accomplish the task in the PySpark shell with the in-built `sc` SparkContext, the program runs on all the nodes; but when I run it as `/bin/pyspark/ --master yarn code.py`, it runs on only two nodes. Is there any parameter I need to tweak to control how many nodes my program runs on?